# How to tell excel to ignore #NUM! errors in plotting a line chart?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, charts

I am plotting a line chart which is a time series. After a certain period of time, the time series shows #NUM! How can I get excel to ignore the #NUM! and plot nothing. Currently, it plots all values of #NUM! as zero which makes my chart inaccurate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using `=IFERROR(A1,NA())`.  This will replace all error values with `NA()`, which Excel will automatically skip giving you a gap.

Comment: NA() or #N/A does not leave a gap. It prevents drawing a marker, but if the other points are connected by a line, Excel draws a line between the points on either side of the #N/A.

Answer (score 5):

You can setup a graph to handle missing data, but not to handle faultive data.

[image: http://www.ucmapi.com/chart/017/gap.png]

So, to solve this you should protect your time-series with a code like:

```
B1=IFERROR(A1;"")
```

Whereby `A1` would be your "raw" data and `B1` is the cell/column which you will have to use as chart-input.

[image]

Comment: how do i get to hidden and empty cell settings?

Comment: choose 'select data source' or so, after a right-click into your chart, then the button at the lft-bottom

Comment: "" is interpreted by Excel as text, and is assigned a value of zero. If you don't want a point at zero, use NA() in the formula instead of "". This puts the ugly #N/A into the cell, but it is not plotted with a point. If the points are connected by lines, a line is drawn connecting the points on either side of the #N/A.